# How do I retain newlines when inserting a variable into a string?

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding in general (at least trying to get good at it anyways) and this is my first StackOverflow question despite lurking here for years and years. My apologies if it's not worded very well.

I've previously written a script that will automatically email people in both text and html with MIMEMultipart for a similar device, but in that one I had a CSV I was pulling the data from. With this new script I get serial data and perform a ser.readline on it. The information is collected from a device over a usb to RS232 cable (I have a raspberry pi that is emulating being the printer basically, receiving the data, and sending the data by email instead).

In the previous script when I was just emailing data from a csv I could use {table} within the string to bring the table into the body of the email and it all worked just fine. However with the new serial script, the newlines aren't being passed through in the same way when I use {ReportData} to insert the serial data into the email body as a string again.

Here's a sanitized version of the code:

```
import serial
import datetime
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# logging settings
logging.basicConfig(filename='SerialError.log', level=logging.INFO)
f = open("Serial.log", "a+")
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  Program Starting.....\r\n")
print("Program Starting.....")
time.sleep(3)

# define variables to open serial connection and report the data
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600, timeout=None)
ReportData = ""

# write to serial log before beginning loop
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") +
        "  Flushing Serial Buffer.......\r\n")
print("Flushing Serial Buffer.......")
ser.reset_input_buffer()
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  Waiting for serial data!\r\n")
print("Waiting for serial data!")
f.close()

# loop to read and process data as received via rs232
while True:
    try:
        ReceiveData = ser.readline().decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
        ReportData += ReceiveData

        # find certain string and consider that the last line
        if ReceiveData.find("string parse for last line i want to read") != -1:
            print(ReportData.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))

            # Text email formatting
            text = """Report Data:
            {ReportData}
            
            """

            # HTML email formatting
            html = """<html><body><p>Report Data:</p>
            {ReportData}

            </body></html>"""

            # email results to recipients
            smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('mail.ourserver.com', 25)
            smtpserver.ehlo()
            smtpserver.starttls()
            smtpserver.ehlo
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative', None, [
                                    MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html, 'html')])
            message['Subject'] = 'Report Data'
            message['From'] = "ReportData<donotreply@mail.ourserver.com>"
            message['To'] = "user@mail.ourserver.com"
            smtpserver.sendmail(
                message['From'], message['To'].split(","), message.as_string())
            smtpserver.close()

    # print errors upon exception
    except Exception as error:
        logging.exception(str(error))
        print("Error: " + str(error))
        exit()
```

If I do:

```
print(ReportData.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))
```

I get:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

Which is what I want, but if I run my code above the email I get looks like this:

```
A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4
```

Which shows me the newline's aren't being brought into it. If I just do print

I have tried other methods of writing out the formatting, such as:

```
# Text email formatting
text = "Report Data:\n", ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore'), "\n"

# HTML email formatting
html = "<html><body><p>Report Data:</p>\n", ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore'), "\n</body></html>"
```

But this results in:

```
Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The reason I added the .encode to try and fix it was I guessed the encoding wasn't passing through, and that was resulting in the newlines being stripped.

I also tried reading the variable into the string by using f-string:

```
# Text email formatting
text = f"Report Data:\n", ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore'), "\n"

# HTML email formatting
html = f"<html><body><p>Report Data:</p>\n", ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore'), "\n</body></html>"
```

but it gave me the same error. Then I tried the original way I wrote it in but with an f-string:

```
# Text email formatting
text = f"""Report Data:
{ReportData}
            
"""

# HTML email formatting
html = f"""<html><body><p>Report Data:</p>
{ReportData}

</body></html>"""
```

And it gives me the original result, just "A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4", etc... Not what I'm looking for.

I can only guess there's some easy answer I'm overlooking after reading a good amount for a couple days, but I can't seem to find it yet.

Does converting the input from ser.readline to a variable make it so using it as a variable within a string keep the newlines from being passed through? If so, what would be the best approach to get around this?

Comment: In HTML, a newline is treated exactly the same as a space.  To actually get a line break to appear, you'd need to replace your newlines with `<br>` or some other appropriate HTML tag.

Comment: You can insert a `<br>` HTML Line Break tag between the rows using `'<br>'.join(ReportData.split('\n'))`.

Comment: When you do `text = "Report Data:\n", ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore'), "\n"`, `text` is a tuple made of three elements (the three strings), which explains the tuple error. You should replace the commas with a + to concatenate the strings.

Comment: @martineau I'm not sure of the kind of syntax I would need to do that and I don't think I understand you very well. If I print the data regularly it looks fine, but when I insert it as a variable into a string it acts as though I did a read instead of a readline, despite the variable I'm inserting into the string using readline, if that makes sense.

Do you have an example that would work for the text email as well? Because the same thing is happening for the text emails.

Comment: @BigBro When I do it the way you suggested with `text = "Report Data:\n"+ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore')+"\n"` I get `Error: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str` now.

Comment: What I said has nothing to do with `read` vs `readline`. All I was saying was if `ReportData` was a string contained `'A 1\nB 2\nC 3\nD 4\n'`, the result of what I suggested would be the string `'A 1<br>B 2<br>C 3<br>D 4<br>'`. In other words, the expression evaluates to a string that has had all the newline characters in `ReportData` replaced with HTML line break tags — which is what you need to put in the HTML version of the email.

Comment: That said, `read()` would be more likely to give you a string with embedded newline characters.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that you cannot expect to drop text into the middle of HTML and expect the same formatting.  HTML doesn't care about `\n` when it renders your page.  It only uses those newlines when you're looking at the HTML *code*.  So that means you have to translate `\n` ==> `<br>` as @martineau mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @martineau . Read my example and see where it says `print(ReportData.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))`. When I do this it shows the data with line breaks, so the previous part where I do `ReceiveData = ser.readline().decode('UTF-8')` and then `ReportData += ReceiveData` seems to retain the newline when I print, but not when I use it as a variable. I am under the impression that your solution to do `'<br>'.join(ReportData.split('\n'))` assumes that the output of `text = "Report Data:\n"+ReportData.encode('UTF-8','ignore')+"\n"` is already working, and it's not.

Comment: Thanks @MarcelWilson - the response from martineau doesn't explain why the newlines are stripped when I use it as a variable in the text email as well, that's my confusion. Sorry if this wasn't clear. :)

Comment: I think you would need to put the expression in the `html = f"""...` statement you have. i.e. change the `{ReportData}` to `{'<br>'.join(ReportData.split('\n'))}`

Comment: @martineau I'll try this, and for fixing the problem with the text email, since <br> won't work in text emails would I have to do the same but `{'\n'.join(ReportData.split('\n'))}` to make it look right (intuitively this doesn't make sense to me though)? I'm asking this because the text emails also don't have the newline in them.

Comment: @martineau regarding using `read()` I tried it and I realized my `if ReceiveData.find...` section won't function anymore. I leave the connection open with `timeout=none` on purpose, and the final thing to be read in isn't predictable, hence why I picked `readline()`, but maybe my approach to all this is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting some of the answers in comment here because code reading is easier.

As martineau suggested `<br>` tags are needed where newlines existed in the original text.  (It's important to note that in HTML you can't just use the original text)

I would build a separate `report_data` just for the html output .

```py
def create_email_html(report_data):
    report_data_html = '<br>\n'.join(report_data.split('\n'))
    return f"""
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Report Data:</p>
    {report_data_html}
    </body>
    </html>"""

html = create_email_html(ReportData)
```

will produce

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Report Data:</p>
A 1<br>
B 2<br>
C 3<br>
D 4<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Which rendered in a browser (or in this case email) will look how you are expecting it to.

Comment: I'm still confused as the output of the text email is still not addressed here. I'm sorry I'm not as knowledgeable to ask the question with proper terminology, which I assume is why I'm being misunderstood... Both the HTML and the Text emails have the same problem of no newlines/line breaks respectively. The newlines are not stripped when I print the ReportData variable, but they are when I insert the variable ReportData into a new variable. Oh haven't tried the f"ReportData" equivalent yet... trying that now...

Comment: This worked! Thanks @martineau and BigBro and MarcelWilson! :) I was almost there with the `f` but still new to all this. Very helpful!

Comment: I'm confused as to what was appearing in the `text` string before.  I would have expected it _not_ show the contents of `"A 1..."` but rather continue to display the string `{ReportData}`.

Comment: The text display earlier was because I didn't preface it with `f`. I had tried `f` before but didn't check my text version of the email that time I did it. Learned to be more thorough in debugging from this.

Comment: @birdybro: Glad you got it figured-out. For future reference, it's usually best to simplify the code as much as possible and provide a [mre] instead of posting a lot of unrelated code — especially when it involves using hardware many of us don't have.

Comment: Adding to what @martineau said about minimal reproducible examples is; this also has the added side effect of making your code better.  It sets you on the path to following [SOLID](https://towardsdatascience.com/solid-coding-in-python-1281392a6a94) principles of programming.

Comment: Thanks! I was kinda struggling with where the problem was and didn't want to leave something out because it might have been missed, but you are right it would have been better if I made an example simplified chunk of code separately just for this to test what is going wrong or right. :)

Comment: I completely understand. I started off programming in python and ran into a lot of the same things you are.  I knew what I wanted to do but simply didn't have the vocabulary to describe the problem.  The thing I learned over time is to break the problem down.  Isolate issues into single responsibility functions.  This way you are only troubleshooting one issue instead of a dozen or so.  In your case you needed to create a string that was going to be used in an email; this could be a good place for functions `create_email_body_text()` and `create_email_body_html()`.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect using a function. Hopefully that helps.